# If cell is "SU" COUNTA previous 6 cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How I can input to formula condition when Excel can recognize that it is cell with value "SU" and if it is perform `=COUNTA(previous 6 cells on row 11)` operation?

Then I can drag that cell with formula below so it will work for the whole range.

In this case it will be false as TH is empty, otherwise if TH will be not empty it should perform calculation.

```
=IF(O11="SU";IF(COUNTA(previous 6 cells on row 11)<6;50;70))
```

So when this formula will reach **U11** `COUNTA` range should be `O11:T11`, when formula will reach **AB11** `COUNTA` range should be `V11:AA11` etc.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a "regular" range reference (i.e. `COUNTA(I11:N11)`)? I think it should work, since Excel uses relative (instead of absolute) references by default, unless you prefix the row/column with `$`.

Comment: This looks to be a matter of fixed versus dynamic (relative) references.  Adding "$" to a range will fix a column or row, depending on position, i.e., `$A1` is fixed column, `A$1` is fixed row, `$A$1` is a fixed cell (column/row), and `A1` is not fixed on either column or row.  @Heinzi 's response should be a an appropriate formula; i am just adding more explanation

Comment: @Heinzi yes I have tried "regular" reference but in my case I need it to be in there only once formula reaches "SU". Not each time for previous 6 cells. See my edited question. Sorry maybe I have described my problem not so well.
I have different cost if person worked 6 days a week for Sunday. If person works less than 6 days a week then cost is 50, if person works 6 days then cost 70.

Comment: Ah I think I got it, it should be `=IF(O9="SU";COUNTA(I11:N11);"")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really unclear.

As I understand, you want to count the number of non-empty cells in the last 6 cells when the day is Sunday. And fill blank if it not Sunday.

The formula for above would be:

```
=IF(O9="SU",COUNTA(I11:N11),"")
```

You can drag this formula horizontally.

**Although COUNTA counts formulas i.e. if a cell contains formula that returns blank then COUNTA would count that as well.

If you have only numbers in the previous 6 cells, then you change COUNTA to COUNT and the above problem will be taken care of.